# Next Js is not picking up my unique "key". What go on?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I can not figure out why my Unique Key is not working. I've done this before and it's worked perfectly fine what does time not working

Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
{props.kokoActors.map((kokoActor) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{kokoActor.id}</h1>
      {/* {kokoActor.role} */}
      <KokoActorCard
        key={kokoActor.id}
        actorName={kokoActor.name}
        role={kokoActor.role}
        imgUrl={kokoActor.imgUrl}
        href={kokoActor.websiteUrl}
      />
      {/* <KokoStarring key={kokoActor.actorID} name={kokoActor.name} role={kokoActor.role} imgUrl={kokoActor.imgUrl} href={kokoActor.websiteUrl} /> */}
    </div>
  );
})}
```

```
const KokoActorCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <StarringBox>
      {/* <Image src={`/image/koko/headshots/${props.name}.jpg`}  width={260} height={260} alt={props.name} /> */}
      {/* <img className="img-contain__staring-home" src={`/img/headshots/${props.name}.jpg`}  /> */}
      <div>
        {" "}
        <br />
        <p>{props.actorName}</p>
        {/* <p >as {role}</p> */}
        {/* <Link href={`/portfolio/patterlabs/koko/${props.href}`} >
              <a>more info</a>
            </Link> */}
      </div>
    </StarringBox>
  );
};

export default KokoActorCard;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over enumerables in JSX you must pass the key property to the first child element returned by the iteration function. In your case a deeper descendant is being assigned the key, not the first child.

Update your code like so:

```
{props.kokoActors.map((kokoActor) => {
  return (
    <div key={kokoActor.id}>
      <h1>{kokoActor.id}</h1>
      {/* {kokoActor.role} */}
      <KokoActorCard
        actorName={kokoActor.name}
        role={kokoActor.role}
        imgUrl={kokoActor.imgUrl}
        href={kokoActor.websiteUrl}
      />
      {/* <KokoStarring key={kokoActor.actorID} name={kokoActor.name} role={kokoActor.role} imgUrl={kokoActor.imgUrl} href={kokoActor.websiteUrl} /> */}
    </div>
  );
})}
```